# Can I access delegate inside another delegate of same class?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I don't know if my understanding is wrong, but I am trying to do something like below:

I have a base class with two delegates:

```
 public class Base
 {
     public Func<bool> Licensed { get; set; }
     public Func<bool> Enabled { get; set; }
 }
```

And a derived class as shown below:

```
public class Derived : Base
{
    public int Test { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I am trying to instantiate derived class in `Main():`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Derived obj = new Derived()
    {
        Licensed = () => { return true; },
        Enabled = () => { return Licensed() && true; }, //access above delegate
     };
}
```

The thing is in `Enabled` implementation, I want to access Licensed delegate assigned just above. I am not able to achieve this as it is not allowed. Is this doable in some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reference other properties in object initializer. C# Language Specification 7.6.10.2 Object initializers:

> It is not possible for the object initializer to refer to the newly
>   created object it is initializing.

But you can use old-fashioned property assignment:

```
var obj = new Derived { Licensed = () => true; };
obj.Enabled = () => obj.Licensed() && true;
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>**Note**: I provide this answer to show some other approach to the OP  to solve the problem. I won't try to say *no, you can't* with a full explanation since this has been already answered by [@SergeyBerezovskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42650293/411632).</sup>

Another option could be turning this into a *fluent API*.

When I need to set *delegates* I tend to think that they should be *set once, never changed*. Therefore, properties holding those delegates should be publicly readable and privately settable.

In the other hand, a fluently-configured object should be created using a *factory method* and its constructor will be `private`.

Finally, each method on the fluent chain should also inject the instance being configured, while you'll end up setting a delegate which calls the one passed as argument to the configuration methods.

That is, you got what you want in a very elegant way.

```
public class Derived : Base
{
     private Derived() {}

     public static Derived Create() => new Derived();

     public Func<bool> Licensed { get; private set; }
     public Func<bool> Enabled { get; private set; }

     public void LicensedIf(Func<Derived, bool> licensingCondition)
            => Licensed = () => licensingCondition(this);

     public void EnabledIf(Func<Derived, bool> enablingCondition)
            => Enabled = () => enablingCondition(this);
}

// Fluent configuration of your *licensable object* gets self-documented
// by the usage!
// Oh, and see how EnableIf() takes advantage of C#6's null conditional
// operator to invoke the "Licensed" delegate if its really set. This is
// so safe!
var derived = Derived.Create().LicenseIf(d => true)
                              .EnableIf(d => d.Licensed?.Invoke() && true);
```

That thing of encapsulating a delegate inside delegate would be called *currying* in functional programming! See [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) if you're interested in this topic.